# Foursquare get venue details but don't need the authentication

Tags: foursquare

I want to get venues from foursquare for iOS app but I don't want to authenticate anymore ?

I'm using the link search API:  https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7,-74&oauth_token=QYGPOWWXAH53L4S5BAJU3TBIC1ZWZGPZMHJYLLZYZOTU4O0Q&v=20131023

Above the link must me sign in foursquare before get data. Can you help me ?

Thank a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the client_id and client_secret parameters instead of oauth_token and make a so called "userless" request. See here instructions on how to generate your client id/secret values: http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xxcmhn_how-to-obtain-foursquare-client-id-and-secret-video-tutorial_tech

Comment: Thank Raluca. It's useful for me. Thumb up for you +1